# Probability about students and exams.

Tags: probability, self-learning

In exams, $80\%$ of the students go prepared and $20\%$ go unprepared.

From the prepared ones, $90\%$ passes the exams.

From the unprepared one, only $10\%$ passes the exams.

**First question**:
If a student passes the exams, what is the probability for him to be prepared?

**Second question**: From $4$ randomly chosen students, what's the probability that **at least** 3 passed the exams?

Comment: Hint: Law of total probability and Bayes' theorem are the tools you need to answer the first question.

Comment: Why did you remove [tag:self-learning]?

Comment: Cause hints get me more confused than helped :(

Comment: I think you are right though, in the end... it's self learning ... with a big help from this community. So this is getting retagged! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's write it in Terms:
$$A:=\text{Student is prepared.}$$
$$B:=\text{Student passes the exam.}$$
We are given
$$\begin{align*}
P(A) & = 0.8 \\
P(\bar{A}) & = 0.2 \\
P(B|A) & = 0.9 \\
P(B|\bar{A}) & = 0.1
\end{align*}$$
The question asks for
  1. $P(A|B)$ and
  2. $P(B)$ combined to a Bernoulli experiment.

---

**1. $P(A|B)%$**
By Bayes' theorem we have
$$P(A|B) = \frac{P(B|A) P(A)}{P(B)}$$
And by total probability we have
$$P(B) = P(B|A) P(A) + P(B|\bar{A}) P(\bar{A}) = 0.9 \cdot 0.8 + 0.1 \cdot 0.2 = 0.74$$
So
$$P(A|B) = \frac{0.9 \cdot 0.8}{0.74} \approx 0.97 $$

---

**2. Bernoulli**
The Question is for
$$X := \sum_{i=1}^4 X_i$$
With $P(X_i = 1) = P(B), X_i \in \{0,1\}$ find
$$P(X \geq 3) = P(X=3) + P(X=4)$$
For $P(X=4)$ we only have $(B,B,B,B)$, so
$$P(X=4) = P(B)\cdot P(B) \cdot P(B) \cdot P(B) = P(B)^4 \approx 0.30$$
For $P(X=3)$ we have $(B,B,B,\bar{B}), (B,B,\bar{B},B), (B,\bar{B},B,B), (\bar{B},B,B,B)$, so
$$P(X=3) = 4\cdot P(B)^3 \cdot P(\bar{B}) = 4\cdot 0.74^3 \cdot 0.26 \approx 0.42$$
And thus
$$P(X\geq 3) \approx 0.72$$

---

In fact, the general formula given $P(X_i) = p$ is
$$P(X=k) = \binom{n}{k} p^k (1-p)^{n-k}$$
Where $n$ is the sample size (here $n=4$).

Comment: I get that you use total probability law because $A + \bar{A} = Ω$ and read about Baye's theorem. Till here we're ok.
Can you help with the second? I have some more problems to post because I mostly understand by examples, but I need to study some more theory from what I see because the second one requires random variables.... Do you think I should post them and let them get answered in time till I finish those extra chapters?

Comment: I'll elaborate on 2. as well, then. Also $A\cup \bar{A} = \Omega$ if $\Omega$ denotes the sample space, yes. Usually, youuse the union sign ($\cup$) instead of the $+$.

Comment: You are right, my bad.

Comment: @user2692669 Is that sufficient? $$\binom{n}{k} = \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$$
The binomial coefficients. The distribution of $X$ is therefor called _binomial distribution_

Comment: X denotes number of students in this problem? I knew that picking k from n items with not caring about orderization is the "binomial coefficient". There is a distribution eh? :)

Comment: $X$ is a (discrete) random variable with binomial distribution. It represents the number of Students (from the sample pick of $n=4$), who passed the exam.

Comment: Does $(x+y)^n = \sum\limits_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} x^k (y)^{n-k}$ have anything to do with the formula for P(X=k) ?

Comment: @user2692669 Somewhat, yes. It's an ugly way of writing
$$1 = 1^n = (p + (1-p))^n = \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} p^k (1-p)^k$$
So this proves that we, in fact, have a distribution ($\sum_{x\in\Omega} P(X=x) = 1$)

Comment: I can't understand the very last sentence but the main formula I get. You sir deserve a Teacher title with a capital T. Green check mark is yours!

Comment: @user2692669 Haha thanks a bunch. The last sentence is a note, that for a distribution $P_X$ per definition we must have, that the probability of the total event, i.e.
$$P(\Omega) = P(X\in\Omega) = \sum_{x\in\Omega} P(X=x)$$
must equal to $1$.

Answer (score 1):

The hard part is that prepared and pass both start with p. So we need to come up with letters other than $P$ as labels for events.

Let $S$ be the event the student Studied. Let $E$ be the event she passed the Exam. We are asked for the conditional probability $\Pr(S|E)$. By the definition of conditional probability,
$$\Pr(S|E)=\frac{\Pr(S\cap E)}{\Pr(E)}.\tag{1}$$

Let us calculate $\Pr(E)$. The event passing the exam can happen in two ways (i) studied and passed or (ii) did not study but passed.

The probability of (i) is $(0.8)(0.9)$. The probability of (ii) is $(0.2)(0.1)$.

Add. We get $\Pr(E)=0.74$.

We found $\Pr(S\cap E)$ already while finding $\Pr(E)$. It is $(0.8)(0.9)$. Divide as per Formula (1).

For the second problem, the probability of passing is $p=0.74$. The probability at least $3$ pass is the probability that $3$ pass plus the probability that $4$ pass. That is a standard *binomial distribution* problem, with answer
$$\binom{4}{3}p^3(1-p)+\binom{4}{4}p^4(1-p)^0.$$