# How many typos are in the document?

Tags: probability, self-learning

We assume that $1\%$ of characters in a document are typos.

We want to find the probability of having **at most** 2 typos inside an 100 characters document.

We want to find it in two ways:

a)Precisely

b)Approximately

---

For **a**:
Let $X$ denote a distinct random variable.
We want $$P(X \le 2) = $$ $$P(X=0)+P(X=1)+P(X=2) =$$
$$\binom{100}{0}(0.01)^0(1-0.01)^{100-0}+\binom{100}{1}(0.01)^1(1-0.01)^{100-1}+\binom{100}{2}(0.01)^2(1-0.01)^{100-2}$$

Is this right?

---

For **b**:

Can someone explain with simple words how do we handle this approximately?

Do we choose always a distribution for this?

And if so, how do we choose the right distribution?

---

**Please KIS (Keep It simple) as much as you can**. Thank you.

This is linked to: [Find the probability for defective diskettes.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/487776/find-the-probability-for-defective-diskettes)

Comment: Why is it 1-.99 inside the brackets??

Comment: I made the calculation in my mind and it poped there, fixed :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The assumption is poorly stated.  Taken literally, it would mean that a 
$100$ character document always has exactly $2$ typos.  What it **should**
say is that each character has probability $0.01$ of being a typo, and 
the characters are independent.

As in the last example, the true distribution is binomial, in this case with 
$n = 100$ and $p = 0.01$.

There are basically two approximations to the binomial distribution that are considered in elementary probability: the Poisson and the normal.  The Poisson distribution is good when $n$ is large and $p$ is small so that $np$ is not too big.  The normal is good when $n$ is large and $p$ is not very close to $0$ or $1$.  In this case $p = 0.01$ is small, so the approximation to use would be Poisson.

EDIT: For interest, the graph below shows, as a function of $p$, the maximum (for integers $x$ from $0$ to $100$) of the error in $P(X \le x)$ when using 
the Poisson distribution (in blue) or the normal distribution with continuity correction (in red), where $X$ is binomial with $n=100$.  From this point of view, Poisson is better for $p < 0.115$ approximately.

[image]

Comment: Maybe they mean something different then, and I misinterpreted it?

Comment: How do we define a "big" $np$?

Comment: One rule of thumb (quoted by Wikipedia) is "the Poisson distribution is a good approximation of the binomial distribution if n is at least 20 and p is smaller than or equal to 0.05, and an excellent approximation if n ≥ 100 and np ≤ 10"

Comment: Robert, green checkmark is yours. If you have time can you check the normal distribution that I (try to) describe in Graphth's answer comment section?

Answer (score 1):

As Robert points out, the Poisson approximation is better in this case.  In this case, the actual answer is about 0.920627, the Poisson approximation gives 0.919699, and the normal approximation with continuity correction gives 0.935133.  I show the normal approximation below as an alternative method that is very helpful in many situations.

Let's assume $X$ denotes the random variable that is 1 if a certain character is a typo and is 0 if it is not.  Then $X$ is a Bernoulli random variable with mean $0.01$ and variance $0.01 \cdot 0.99 = 0.0099$.  If we have 100 characters, it's as if we have 100 independent random variables, $X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_{100}$, added together, where each $X_i$ is the same distribution I just described for $X$.  Therefore, the Central Limit Theorem tells us that this sum is approximately normal.  So, we start by finding the mean and variance of the sum
$$Z = X_1 + X_2 + \cdots + X_{100}.$$
First, we have
$$E[Z] = E[X_1] + E[X_2] + \cdots + E[X_{100}] = 100 E[X] = 100 \cdot 0.01 = 1$$
and for the variance, we have
$$Var[Z] = Var[X_1] + Var[X_2] + \cdots + Var[X_{100}] = 100 \cdot Var[X] = 100 \cdot 0.0099 = 0.99.$$
So, we know that $Z$ is approximately normal with mean $1$ and variance $0.99$.  So, we calculate the probability $P(Z \leq 2)$ by calculating $P(N \leq 2.5)$, where $N$ is a normal random variable with mean 1 and variance 0.99.  This will approximate $P(Z \leq 2)$.  Using $N \leq 2.5$ is called a continuity correction.  The point is, the only values of this random variable are integers, $0, 1, 2, \ldots$.  So, by using the continuity correction, we get half the amount between 2 and 3, which makes it more accurate.

Hopefully you can take it from there.

Comment: The normal distribution, especially without the continuity correction, is a very poor approximation in a case such as this.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Thanks for the info.  I have changed my answer to be an alternative solution to your better solution, because the alternative solution is helpful in other situations.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong:When we say **mean** we talk about the **average value**? When we say **variance** we talk about **average divergence from the average value**? I found this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution but how did we choose the mean and the variance values (on what criteria)? Obviously I can't take it from there :(

Comment: mean is average value, as you said, and variance is average squared deviation, not just average deviation.  This ensures, for example, that the variance is always positive (or possibly 0 for a distribution that always returns the same value).  It also ensures that the variance deviations don't cancel each other out, as would be possible if we used just average deviation.  So, $Var(X) = \frac{\sum (x_i - \bar{x})^2}{n} = E[X^2] - (E[X])^2$.

Comment: Can you finish the problem please? Normal distribution is ${1\over  \sqrt{2*\pi*σ^2} }  {e^{-{(x-μ)^2\over2σ^2}}} $ , how do I use this ? $ σ^2 = Var[Z]$ ? $μ = E[Z]$? For $x$ do I use values $0,1,2$?

Answer (score 0):

Another approach could be the Poisson distribution, since the p-value is very small.
THis formula can be found here:
http://infinity.cos.edu/faculty/woodbury/stats/tutorial/Pois_Form.htm
The expection lambda is np, here 1, and x is going from 0 to 2. Apply formula 3 times.